# Mobile version - extra width due to the navbar

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am a self taught programmer and I finished the mobile version of my website few days ago with a navbar on the right side (pictures bellow). My problem is I am able to scroll right and left because of that and it does not looks good at all. Is there any way to lock it? I already have `overflow-x:hidden;` for the body so I do not get it

navbar hidden:
[image]

navbar displayed:
[image]

```
/* NavBar */  
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){


body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}    

.burger{
    margin-right:1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    background-color:white;
    width: 27px;
    height: 3px;
    margin:5px;
}

.nav-links{
    background-color: #5286ec;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    height: 85vh;
    top:65px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

#navbar ul li{
    margin: 2rem 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity:0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }to{
        opacity:1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set overflow of your navbar container to hidden `overflow: hidden;`  the problem is you are moving it out of the box but it still exists 
you can also set body, html overflow to hidden but its not right

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to prevent the scrollbar from appearing and the ability to scroll left & right, you can add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `html` and `body` elements in CSS.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You can just add `html` to your `body` selector